# Ajax start image (loading image) shows for first ajax call but fails on subsequent ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am failry new to jQuery. I am trying to get a div (loading_div) to show during Ajax calls and then disappear when the ajax call finishes. This work fine for the first call but subsequent calls do not trigger the loading_div. I know this is a basic issue related to the DOM, and there is at least one similar question on stack about this, but its not really exactly the same. I have failed to modify the answer to suit my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $(function(){
   var $loading = $('.loading_div').hide();
   $(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $loading.show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $loading.hide();
    });
 });
```

Tried this...(altered the HTML see below)..but still no luck. I though adding the on() would help. Anyone?.....pulling my hair out at this point. To give some more background, this is an implementation of the load dots jQuery plugin. The plugin works and the first ajax call triggers the function below. Its just subsequent calls will not trigger it unless i refresh the page.

HTML

```
      <div class="loading_div">

      </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on("ajaxSend", function(){
    $('.loading_div').append($('#loadingdots'));
    })
    $(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $('.loading_div').remove($('#loadingdots'));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AjaxSend()` and `AjaxComplete()`. The methods you are using are meant to run only the first ajax call.

Comment: This, like my function above, works for the first ajax call but not for subsequent calls. Again, as a beginner, this may seem simplistic but I am assuming this is something to do with delegation - I am wondering if using $(document.body).on......  syntax would work. I have tried this and it doesn't but as a newbie, I am uncertain if my syntax is absolutely correct.